# Rails has_many unique scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models

```rb
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ads
end
```

```rb
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :platform
  validates :platform, uniqueness: { scope: :campaign }
end
```

Basically, in a single campaign I can't have two ads belonging to the same platform.

What I am trying to achieve is reach a clean way to implement a scope to retrieve the ad for each for platform.
**Example:**

```
Campaign.find(1).facebook
```

or

```
Campaign.find(1).ads.facebook
```

Would return the only facebook ad for this campaign.

Should this scope be implemented on the campaigns model or the ads model & how would you do it?

All ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the list of platforms hardcoded? Or do you want the methods to be dynamical?

Comment: @SiimLiiser they are dynamic & stored in the DB. But if you have a proposal on how to do it if they are hardcoded, please go ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `for_platform` scope in your Ad model

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :platform
  validates :platform, uniqueness: { scope: :campaign }
  scope :for_platform, -> (platform) { where(platform: Platform.find_by(name: platform) }
end

my_campain.ads.for_platform(:facebook).take
```

If you want a `facebook` method you could do that with the above and `method_missing` on `Campaign`

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :platform
  validates :platform, uniqueness: { scope: :campaign }
  scope :for_platform, -> (platform) { where(platform: Platform.find_by(name: platform) }
end

class Campaign < ApplicationRecord

  private

  def method_missing(m, *args, @block)
    if Platform.find_by(name: m)
      return ads.for_platform(m).take
    end
    super
  end  
end

my_campain.facebook # assumes there's a platform with name 'facebook'
```

Comment: Thank you @SteveTurczyn for your proposal! I extended it a bit & what I ended up doing is in the Campaign model I added ```has_one :facebook_ad, lambda {merge(Ad.for_platform("facebook"))}, class_name: "Ad"```. This way I could call ```my_campaign.facebook``` safely